# No bluetooth earphones as sound input device

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, input-devices

My bluetooth earphones, which work completely fine in windows on the same machine, has a problem on Ubuntu 20.04.
After connecting the earphones via bluetooth in Ubuntu, the sound output device sets to the bluetooth earphones, but the sound input doesn't. In the menu of input devices too, there is only system microphone shown.

Please tell, how to choose bluetooth earphones as sound input device.

I have searched pretty much on the internet, but can't find a solution.

Comment: Hey theprodaddy! Please [edit] your question and mention the name and model of the earphones.

Comment: is that matter? @RandomPerson bcz I;ve a same problem with all of my bluetooth earphone. I think it's a problem about my earphone, but when I buy a new one, it still not working on ubuntu but working on windows

Comment: @BariqDharmawan It could be because of earphones or it could be because of the Bluetooth & audio drivers or some other reason. Having extra details in the question is always good :)

Comment: Hmm make sense @RandomPerson